# In what way is it possible to increase the title's size?

Tags: formatting, lyx, titles, fontsize

Hi I am writing my thesis with LyX. It is quite user-friendly, however I am not able to get a title bigger than the maximum available with the default settings, which actually is not so big. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could we see the class in use?

Comment: ...and a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) showing what you have tried.

Comment: \title{\scalebox{2.0}{...}} using the graphicx pacakge.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in a latex box (create via ctrl + l) right before the first letter of the title (the box should appear somewhat large)

```
\fontsize{80pt}{0pt}\selectfont
```

The first parameter is the desired font size which you'll need to adjust to your liking, the second one controlls line spacing. If your title only spans one line it won't matter, if it spans several you'll have to adjust to your liking.

Comment: The second value should be larger than the first one, it represents the distance between baselines.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the displayed title size in LyX by adding the following Document > Settings... > Local Layout:

```
Format 60

Style Title
Margin                Static
LatexType             Command
Category              FrontMatter
InTitle               1
LatexName             title
ParSkip               0.4
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0
BottomSep             1
ParSep                1
Align                 Center
LabelType             No_Label
Font
  Size                Huge
EndFont
HTMLTag               h1
HTMLTitle             true
End
```

If you want to change the PDF output title size, you can either select the title and change the Edit > Text Style > Customized... > Size where you can choose (say) Huge or Huger.

The following patch will also do the same, changing the PDF output title size to `\Huge`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\@title}% <search>
  {\Huge\@title}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Or, if you're not into loading packages:

```
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\Huge #1}}
\makeatother
```

The above changes the font size, which limits you to the font. However, you could also resize the title using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox` or `\scalebox`. Here's one Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble patch that uses the former to stretch the title so it's 50% of the `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\resizebox{.5\textwidth}{!}{#1}}}
\makeatother
```